# Why we can reuse a moved socket_ in acceptor_.async_accept?

Tags: c++, boost, asio, beast

Reference: `https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html`

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
...
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service); 
// you have to initialize socket with io_service first before 
//you can use it as a parameter on async_accept.
acceptor.async_accept(socket, accept_handler);
```

Reference:

```
https://github.com/vinniefalco/CppCon2018/blob/master/listener.cpp

listener::  listener(
    net::io_context & ioc,
    tcp::endpoint endpoint,
    std::shared_ptr < shared_state >
    const & state): acceptor_(ioc), socket_(ioc), state_(state) {

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener>
{
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
...
}

// Handle a connection
void listener::  on_accept(error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
      return fail(ec, "accept");
    else
      // Launch a new session for this connection
      std::make_shared < http_session > (
        std::move(socket_),                    // socket_ is moved here?
        state_) -> run();

    // Accept another connection
    acceptor_.async_accept(
      socket_,                                 // why we still can use it here?
      [self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) {
        self -> on_accept(ec);
      });
  }
```

Based on my understanding, `std::move(socket_)` allows the compiler to cannibalize `socket_`. In other word, the `listener::socket_` originally initialized by `socket_(ioc)` will become uninitialized.

Question> How can we give an uninitialized `socket_` to `acceptor_.async_accept`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the implementation of the types.

We can loosely describe the *intent* of a move as "the compiler is allowed to cannibalize". But really, for user-defined types **we're** going to have to tell it how to do that, exactly.

In language "doctrine" a moved-from object may only be assumed safe to destruct, but in practice many libraries make more lenient guarantees (e.g. keeping all the invariants, or making sure that a moved-from object is comparable to a newly constructed one).

Indeed, ASIO [documents](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload9.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_stream_socket.basic_stream_socket.overload9.remarks) this:

> #### Remarks
>
> Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_stream_socket(const executor_type&) constructor.